# capacitance of cube skeleton

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

A cube of 12 capacitors is very common problem. find capaciance accross edges we get 12c/7.
But lets say we have 8 more capacitors involved now.
that is we have capacitors at all sides of cube and also at all digonals ( face and body). now how to find capacitance accross any edge.

Comment: What makes this materially different from the 12 capacitor cube case?

Comment: how to resolve them.